# Non closed subgroup of an algebraic group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

What's an example of a non closed subgroup of an (affine) algebraic group? Also, is $\Bbb A^0$ an algebraic group?

(In particular, over $\Bbb C$)

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}   $

Comment: @Plinytheill How are these affine algebraic?

Comment: you want the subgroup to be algebraic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $A^0 = \{pt\}$ is an algebraic group, with multiplication the constant map  $A^0 \times A^0\to A^0$.

An example of a non-closed subgroup is $S^1 \subset \Bbb C^*$. For something more fancy you can take the graph of the exponential function which is a subgroup of $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C^*$, it is analytic but not algebraic.

Comment: Am I right that your example of $S^1$ would be closed if we were working over $\mathbb{R}$ (or smaller rings), and it only fails to be closed when we work over $\mathbb{C}$ as the base ring?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Yes exactly !

Comment: Ahh, good (my first impression on seeing the example was "but the norm is given by polynomials").

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : yes, and in my opinion real algebraic geometry is cooler (but well the OP asked over $\Bbb C$ :) )

Comment: I prefer algebraically closed fields, I just also like algebraic groups in positive characteristic (as that is where all the interesting rational representations are).